# Android tools:listitem

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-view

I have custom view, which have recycler view as part of it

How can I set `tools:listitem` for preview by custom view attributes?

I want set it this way

```
 <declare-styleable name="MyCustomViewWithRecycler">
        <attr name="my_list_item" format="reference" />
 </declare-styleable>

 <MyCustomView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:my_list_item="@layout/my_item"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple use of `tools:listitem` that allows you to replace the randoms lines of a `ListItem` or a `RecyclerView` line in the Android Studio layout editor.

If you have a `CustomView` Recycler like this

```
<MyCustomView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        tools:listitem="@layout/my_list_item"/>
```

I hope, it solves your problem.